# Pandas でCSV ファイルの読み込み時にエラー UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81

Tags: python, pandas

CSVファイルの読み込みができません。

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#data input
df_2021 = pd.read_csv('2021.csv',engine="python")
df＿2021
```

結果

```
>>> #data input
>>> df_2021 = pd.read_csv('2021.csv',engine="python")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 575, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 933, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1235, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 115, in __init__
    ) = self._infer_columns()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 364, in _infer_columns
    line = self._buffered_line()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 596, in _buffered_line
    return self._next_line()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 696, in _next_line
    orig_line = self._next_iter_line(row_num=self.pos + 1)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py", line 760, in _next_iter_line
    line = next(self.data)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 441: invalid start byte
>>> df_2021
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'df_2021' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のエラーはShift_JIS(CodePage932)エンコーディングされたCSVファイルをUTF-8エンコーディング(pandasのデフォルト)で読み取ろうとした時に発生するものです。

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 441: invalid start byte
```

対処方法としては以下のいずれかになるでしょう。

- CSVファイル自体をUTF-8エンコーディングで作成するか、メモ帳やエディタ等でエンコーディングを変換してセーブする。
- `pd.read_csv()`で読み取る際に、パラメータに`encoding='cp932'`を追加してエンコーディングを指定する。

Comment: encoding='cp932'を追加すると表示することができました。ありがとうございます。